# Ora-01031: insufficient privileges on the table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to the table of its same schema(user is the owner of the table)
connecting to DB using user GOBI.
Insert into GOBI.table1(A,B,C) values (a,b,c)

Why am i getting this error even when i am trying to insert the data to the owner's table.

Comment: You have missing `grants` on the table. You must grant the user from which you are trying to access the table.

Comment: Hello XING, My user is the Owner of the table itself

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to execute this insert from the user you logged on ? Might

Comment: Yes i am using the same user who is the owner of the table

Comment: Do you succeed in the DML operation, when you issue `Insert into table1(A,B,C) values (a,b,c)` without `GOBI.` prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us the SQL you used? Without the details, I cannot reproduce your error, it's working for me:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,2,3);
1 row inserted.
```

Comment: @Nimantha: why did you remove the link to the "How to ask a question" page?

Comment: "How to ask a question" would be better suited as a comment posted under the question.